# Task manager says a program is running but I can't see it

Tags: windows

Task manager says a program is running but I can't see it. Windows version is vista and program is curationsoft. 
I have already closed program in the task manager and then re-running it. Same thing, task manger says it is running but I cant see anything.
even tried to uninstall and reinstall but same thing.
How Can I see it?
Is it bugged?

Comment: Tasks don't have to be visual! Things are running on your machine all the time (look up Windows Services for an example)

Comment: I have the icon on desktop, along with all the other icons. It doesn't show in task bar.

Comment: I can't seem to tell if anything is wrong with it. ALthough I noticed that in properties it has a size of zero bytes but in the c:\ programs it is listed as having bytes. Not sure if this means something or not.     I tried reinstalling but no luck.     It worked fine at first then stopped working.     Wondering if I should just ask for money back as it is worthless if I can't use it.

Comment: Have you rebooted? Tried in Safe Mode? Log into another profile?

Comment: Or even just killing the task from task manager? If it previously crashed, it might not have shut down completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to see a window then check that your resolution is not set up to multiple displays. The application may be on a display that does not exist. You can also hold the windows key and keep tapping left, up or the right arrows to see whether the application displays on your current monitor.

Also it may be worth checking in your notifications bar (bottom right hand corner by the clock) check to see whether it is down there as it may be hidden. If this is the case you should be able to right click and show the form through the options or simply double click.

Failing that, go back to the developer.

Comment: Screen seems ok.   Can't find it by taping arrows or anything.   I can stop it from running with the manager but if i try to reopen it  it is the same.  task manager says it is open  but nowhere to be saw.

Comment: Worked fine and then not any more.  Reinstalling doesn't seem to work. Developer said it must be with my computer, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Oh, they did say to check windows log viewer and see if the program is there but so far at least I haven't seen it.

Comment: If it does not happen with any other product then you need to go back to the developer again.